# Onchange form filter with dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to create a filter for a gallery that I've created. The gallery has 5 filters using dropdown menu's. When a item is selected from one of the 5 filters it has to filter the images. When a second filter is selected it has to filter the results of the first filter and so on.

I am using the `onchange='this.form.submit()'` script but I don't know how to assign a certain action to it when an item is selected. This is my code at the moment of writing:

```
<td>
    Kleur:
    <form method="POST">
        <select name="kleur" onchange='this.form.submit()'>
            <option> -- Geen optie -- </option>
            <?php while ($line1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $line1['kleur']; ?>"> <?php echo $line1['kleur']; ?>
                </option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </form>

    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $kleur = $_POST['kleur'];
        $SQL = "SELECT * FROM `rozen` WHERE `kleur` LIKE '$kleur'";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
        echo $result;
    }
    ?>

    </br>
</td>
```

The following part doesn't seem to work:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $kleur = $_POST['kleur'];
    $SQL = "SELECT * FROM `rozen` WHERE `kleur` LIKE '$kleur'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
    echo $result;
}
?>
```

Does anyone know how to use this script? and perhaps explain how to save the selected item in the dropdown menu too?

Comment: i think reload the page for each filter action its not a good idea... you need to bind a jquery change event to the select and then hide or show images based on selection.. but can you show something more about the gallery??

Comment: @Vanojx1

The gallery i'm working on is located at http://82.74.55.31/bbs/public/rozen.php

Answer (score 0):

You can add an attribute with all the information you need to filter to your images

```
<img filterInfo="Kleur|Geur|Bloemvorm|Gezondheid|Type|Zoeken">
```

then set a class for all your filters to catch the changes

```
$(".filters").on("change",function(){
    var kleur = $('[name=Kleur]').val();
    var Geur = $('[name=Geur]').val();
    ...
    ...
    ...

    $.each($('#gallery img'),function(i,v){
        var attrs = $(v).attr("filterInfo").slice("|");
        if((kleur == "" || kleur == attrs[0]) && (Geur == "" || == attrs[1]) .... other filters)
            $(this).show(); //or fadeIn();
        else
            $(this).hide(); //or fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Comment: I am not sure how to implement this in my code, I get the data of my images from my database by using:

    $query1 = "SELECT kleur FROM rozen GROUP BY kleur"; 
 $result1 = mysqli_query($connection, $query1);

Comment: with that code you populate gallery... you don't need any other call to that query... and no page reload... you dont need anymore the onchange event on your select... my code check for changes on your filters and loop trough images and hide or show who match or not the filters